# Plank Has Fuzzy Secondary icons

Tags: plank

All applications on plank have a second fuzzy icon, like this:
[image: fuzzy plank]
How can I fix this? It happens with all applications.

Comment: Don't use pictures from other posts.Also this is a duplicate of the post you got the picture from

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure chrome is not running, and remove icon from the dock
2. Run `sudo pantheon-files`
3. Go to : `/usr/share/applications`
4. Open Google Chrome configuration file with text editor
5. At the bottom of: `[Desktop Entry]` right below this line: `(X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts)`. Add this line: `StartupWMClass=Google-chrome-stable`
6. Save and exit